# Inverse of binary funcation

Tags: inverse, poisson-distribution

Is it possible to get the inverse function $f^{-1}(y)$ from the one below? Don't really know how to handle $\mathbf{1}_{\{ p(k)\leq x\}}$.
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\mathbf{1}_{\{ p(k)\leq x\}}
$$
Thank you.

Comment: What is $p$ here? Anyway, that indicator function basically just makes it a finite sum for each $x$.

Comment: p is a function st. $p(x)\in (0,1)$. So for $x>1$, $\mathbf{1}_{\{ p(k)\leq 1 \}}=1$.

Comment: Unless $\{p(k) \mid k \in\Bbb N\}$ is dense in $(0,1)$, $f$ will not be invertible. If there is some interval which does not contain any of the $p(k)$, then $f$ will be constant on that interval, and so is not one-to-one. For example, if $p$ is an increasing function, then $f(x)$ will only take on countably many values on the uncountable interval (0,1).

Comment: That is the CDF of a Poisson distribution (a discrete distribution) so is not surjective onto $[0,1)$ and thus does not have an inverse in usual function language, I would prefer to call it $F(x)$.  You may be asking for the quantile function $Q(y)\,=\,\inf\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R} : y \lt F(x) \right\}$ which here will give you a non-negative integer result for any $y\in [0,1)$.  It is not a simple calculation, but it is implemented in good statistical languages.  For example R has `ppois(q,lambda)` for your function and `qpois(p,lambda)` as its quantile function